# Basic Probability - Semi-Final Draw

Tags: probability

If you have a random draw for the semi-finals of a competition (say football), with teams A, B, C & D (equal probability that each is drawn), whereby each team is drawn from a hat one after another - what are the odds that team A will play team D?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean the odds that team A will play team D in the semi-finals, or that team A will play team D in the rest of the competition? For the latter, you'd also need the probabilities for the teams to beat each other.

Comment: Just that A will play D in the semi-final.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to list all the possible cases:

1. A against B and C against D
2. A against C and B against D
3. ....

and so on. There are exactly 24 cases. You can then simply count (all cases are equi-probable).

Another option is to use symmetry arguments: the probability that A will play with D is the same as the probability that A will play with B. The same goes for C. Since it will play with one of them, the sum of all these should be 1. See where this is headed?

Comment: My instinct said 1/3, for obvious reasons, but then wasn't sure if there is a really simple formula. Can you use conditional probabilities in this case i.e. pr(A|D) + pr(D|A) or will it not work because of the two possible semi final places.

Comment: The answer is indeed 1/3 as you said. What does $\operatorname{pr}(A|D)$ stand for?